# Bazel run vs test

Tags: spring, testing, h2, junit4, bazel

What's the difference between `bazel test` vs `bazel run` on the the java test rule? When I run the `bazel run` command, my test passes just fine, while with `bazel test` I get an error. If needed, I can provide more details, but I was interested in general differences between those two commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bazel test launches the test in an isolated container. Due to this any default environment variable that were not explicitly set would not be available for test system.
A typical example would be HELM_HOME being blank in bazel test.

Answer (score 0):

You [can run a single test target](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#executing-tests) with `bazel run`. `bazel test` is [highly parallel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#test), has [more options](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#options-for-bazel-test) regarding tests and better reporting.